# How to solve this stored procedure issue?

Tags: sql-server

I created this stored procedure in SQL Server 2017, and apparently it worked at first but suddenly it just stopped working.

This is supposed to validate whether a car has already entered in a parking lot or not. If it hasn't it creates the row and in the vehicle table and creates the row in vehicle payment table. If this is not the case it just creates the row in in the vehicle payment table and updates the state to (meaning it's currently in).

```
--table names, fields and variables are in spanish
CREATE TABLE Estacionamiento.Vehiculo
(
    id INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Vehiculo_Estacionamiento_id
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id),
    tipoVehiculo INT NOT NULL,
    placa NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        CONSTRAINT CHK_Formato_Placa_Vehiculo
        CHECK (placa LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
    estado BIT NOT NULL
)
GO

--Crear la tabla PagoVehiculo
CREATE TABLE Estacionamiento.PagoVehiculo
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Vehiculo_PagoVehiculo_id
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id),
    vehiculo INT NOT NULL,
    fechaHoraEntrada DATETIME NOT NULL,
    fechaHoraSalida DATETIME NOT NULL,
    total DECIMAL NOT NULL
)
GO

--The problem is here
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_InsercionVehiculosEntradasSalidas
    (@placa NVARCHAR(8),
     @tipoVehiculo NVARCHAR(15))
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @placaVehiculo INT
        DECLARE @horaEntrada DATETIME
        DECLARE @horaSalida DATETIME

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Estacionamiento.Vehiculo WHERE placa = @placa AND tipoVehiculo = @tipoVehiculo)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Estacionamiento.Vehiculo (placa, tipoVehiculo, estado)
            VALUES (@placa, @tipoVehiculo, 1)

            SET @placaVehiculo = (SELECT id FROM Estacionamiento.Vehiculo WHERE placa = @placa)

            INSERT INTO Estacionamiento.PagoVehiculo (vehiculo, fechaHoraEntrada, fechaHoraSalida, total)
            VALUES (@placaVehiculo, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 0)
        END
        ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Estacionamiento.Vehiculo WHERE placa = @placa)
        BEGIN
            SET @placaVehiculo = (SELECT id FROM Estacionamiento.Vehiculo WHERE placa = @placa)
            PRINT(@placaVehiculo)

            IF (SELECT estado FROM Estacionamiento.Vehiculo WHERE placa = @placa) = 0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Estacionamiento.PagoVehiculo (vehiculo, fechaHoraEntrada, fechaHoraSalida, total)
                VALUES (@placaVehiculo, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 0)

                UPDATE Estacionamiento.Vehiculo 
                SET estado = 1
            END
            ELSE IF (SELECT estado FROM Estacionamiento.Vehiculo WHERE placa = @placa) = 1
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Estacionamiento.PagoVehiculo 
                SET fechaHoraSalida = GETDATE() 
                WHERE vehiculo = @placaVehiculo  
                  AND id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Estacionamiento.PagoVehiculo)

                SET @horaEntrada = (SELECT MAX(fechaHoraEntrada) 
                                    FROM Estacionamiento.PagoVehiculo 
                                    WHERE vehiculo = @placaVehiculo)
                SET @horaSalida = (SELECT MAX(fechaHoraSalida) 
                                   FROM Estacionamiento.PagoVehiculo 
                                   WHERE vehiculo = @placaVehiculo)

                UPDATE Estacionamiento.Vehiculo 
                SET estado = 0

                UPDATE Estacionamiento.PagoVehiculo 
                SET total = dbo.Fctn_CalculoPagoVehiculo(@horaEntrada, @horaSalida, @tipoVehiculo) 
                WHERE vehiculo = @placaVehiculo
                  AND id = (SELECT MAX(id) 
                            FROM Estacionamiento.PagoVehiculo)
            END
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @error INT

        SET @error = @@ERROR

        RETURN @error
    END CATCH
GO
```

I'm expecting to validate and insert and update when needed.

Comment: So if its not working, what is it actually doing? Nothing? Something incorrect? Can your provide some sample data which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Simply repeating the same text over and over again to bypass the minimum length requirements is inappropriate here. The requirement exists to get you to properly describe the problem, and repeating the same thing does not do so. Please [edit] your question to properly and clearly describe the issue you're having.

Comment: Well, rigth now it does nothing. For example: if I execute the SP with parameters 'ASD-1235', 'Sedan' it should validate whether the car has never been in the parking lot or not, if that's the case it should insert the vehicle row and the vehicle payment row. If it has it should update the car payment row and update the state in vehicle table. Right it just returns "Commands completed successfully." instead of "# of rows affected".

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Eating the error in your stored procedure does not help the caller understand what happened.

Comment: TipoVehiculo should probably be a FK to a type table. And why do you use a nvarchar(15) parameter to your procedure to set this column in your procedure? Implicit conversion will lead to more problems (which are eaten by your error handling logic). Lastly - placa is unique so your first IF sql statement is logically incorrect.

Comment: And PagoVehiculo.vehiculo should obviously be a FK to the first table. You define PagoVehiculo.total as decimal without precision or scale - do you understand what that does? Seems you need to work on your schema first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things that I am noticing as I read your proc:

In some places you check for a unique car in the `vehiculo` table by doing :

```
WHERE placa = @placa AND tipoVehiculo = @tipoVehiculo
```

and other places by doing just

```
WHERE placa = @placa
```

Be consistent in your code depending on which gives you the unique car

When the car is inserted into `PagoVehiculo`, you are populating both the entry and exit dates with the current date. While not technically wrong, I would expect the exit date to be null until the car exits. That will help with clarity of the data.

There are many places where you check `select *`, you can instead `select 1`, which will perform better

There is no `ELSE` statement to catch unexpected situations and report and issue.

At one point you are trying to get the id of the pagoVehiculo table for a particular car by doing:

```
id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Estacionamiento.PagoVehiculo)
```

There is no guaranty that will retrieve the correct car (specially since you could have multiple clients writting to the table at the same time. Add an additional clause to ensure you are pulling data for the right car. something like:

```
id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Estacionamiento.PagoVehiculo where vehiculo = @placaVehiculo)
```

In terms of what is going on with the proc, My guess is that is either failing silently or it is not falling into the IF or the ELSE IF and thus just skipping the whole thing. I would debug this as follows (after reviewing the comments :

1. Add and ELSE statement in the main If statement to catch unexpected situations
2. Add a print statement in the IF section , ELSE If and ELSE sections (something like `print ('in IF statement')` so that you know which branch is executing (or you can just debug it , if you are familiar with SQL Proc debugging)
3. Remove the `try catch` section and see if there is an exception that is being catched and not rethrown for some reason.

Oh and I just saw, `tipoVehiculo` is defined as `INT` in the table , but you are passing a NVARCHAR(15) in the proc, which is prob why you have the problem.